# How to resolve OwinContext from Unity Container?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, unity-container

I have an application that is written using c# on the top of Asp.Net MVC 5 framework.

I added [Unity.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/) package to my project so I can take advantage of dependency injections. Everything is working fine except when I try to log a user in.

From with in my `AccountController` I am trying to use the injected `ApplicationUserManager` to find a user by name like so `UserManager.FindByName(username)`

But that line keeps throwing the following error

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'ApplicationUserManager'
```

I understand the error here, but not sure what is causing the disposal of the object.

Here is a stripped version of my `AccountController` where I interact with the `ApplicationUserManager` object.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    protected ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager;
    protected ApplicationUserManager UserManager;
    protected IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager { get; set; }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
        AuthenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }


    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SignIn(string username)
    {

        var user = UserManager.FindByName(username); // this line throws an error
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("User not found!");
        }

        SignInManager.SignIn(user, true, false);

        //...
    }
}
```

In `UnityConfig` class, I register my both `ApplicationSignInManager` and `ApplicationUserManager` like so

```
container.RegisterType<ApplicationUser>();
container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>();
container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IUserPassport, UserPassport>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

Then in my `Startup.Auth` class I have the following

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>());
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationSignInManager>());

    //....
}
```

What could be disposing the `ApplicationSignInManager` instance? How can I get this to work?

**UPDATE**

I also tried to register my objects using different life-time managers like `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`, `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` and `ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager`

```
container.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: Did you follow [this article](https://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/)

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I just updated my code to match the code in the article you posted. now, the same line of code gives me the following error `Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'UserStore`1'.`

Comment: So have you registered all the dependencies?

Comment: @Nkosi yes. I just updated the question with all the types that are identity related and registered